# what does `...` do in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab but I thought `...` is used for expressing array. Following lines of code, however, proved that I had no idea what that does. Could anybody give me a clue?

```
 str = sprintf('%s: sometext %d of %d, sometext %d [%d-other text %d]',...
            GROUP(ID).Name,...
            GROUP(ID).TurnNumber+1,...
            GROUP(ID).MaxTurns,...
            GROUP(ID).SetNumber,...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the line continuation string; basically, it means treat the end of line character you're about to encounter as if it didn't exist.

Invalid because of the line break:

```
str = sprintf('%s foo',
           'foo');
```

Valid because you tell Matlab to keep reading:

```
str = sprintf('%s foo', ...
           'foo');
```

Comment: Oh well. I guess I am aging and slow. :-) Thanks so much for your prompt answer.