# What does /... mean in Matlab?

Tags: javascript, matlab

I'm trying to translate an equation from MATLAB to Javascript

```
K = 2*abs((x2-x1).*(y3-y1)-(x3-x1).*(y2-y1)) ./ ...
   sqrt(((x2-x1).^2+(y2-y1).^2)*((x3-x1).^2+(y3-y1).^2)*((x3-x2).^2+(y3-y2).^2));
```

What does `./ ...` mean here?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html

Comment: @Andreas Hmm, how about the `./` ? I can't search through Google for special characters since Google ignores them in the search

Comment: `./ `appears to be a (vector/array) divider
`...` appears to be a line or function continuation

Comment: The above equation involves bare `*` (without dot(.)) in the second line, which means a matrix product rather than element-wise multiplication. So for example, a' * b * c means something like dot_product(a,b) * c(:) (if we assume a, b, c are column vectors, with single quote(') means transpose). So, the second line may need caution. Hmm...

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does \`...\` do in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302057/what-does-do-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... represents a line continuation, while `./` means that the division will be performed in an element-wise way. So for example, `c = a ./ b` means `for all elements, do c(i) := a(i) / b(i)`. Similarly, `.*` and `.^` represent element-wise multiplication and exponentiation.

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html for the "official" explanation of `.`